# Android Studio, RecyclerView crashes my app on start up

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am battling with the android Recyclerviewer. I followed most tutorials and also read posts here on StackOverflow, but i am still not coming right.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
RecyclerView myrecyclerView;
MyAdapter adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myrecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.myRecycleView);
    adapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, getData());
    final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    myrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    myrecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    myrecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    //
}
//the Dataset
public static List<MyDataModel> getData()
{
    List<MyDataModel> myData = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] postText = {"ibm", "apple", "google", "microsoft"};
    int[] postImgUrl = {R.drawable.google, R.drawable.ibm, R.drawable.microsoft, R.drawable.apple};

    for(int x=0; x<postText.length && x<postImgUrl.length; x++)
    {
        MyDataModel myModel = new MyDataModel();
        myModel.postImgUrl = postImgUrl[x];
        myModel.postText = postText[x];
        myData.add(myModel);
    }
    return myData;
}
```

MyAdapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>{

List<MyDataModel> MyDataset;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
public MyAdapter(Context cont, List<MyDataModel> MyDataset)
{
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(cont);
}

public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int ViewType)
{
    //get ItemLayoutView from xml
    View itemLayoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_items_row, parent, false);
    //pass it to the ViewHolder
    ViewHolder myViewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    return myViewHolder;
}

public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position)
{
    viewHolder.postText.setText(MyDataset.get(position).postText);
    viewHolder.postImage.setImageResource(MyDataset.get(position).postImgUrl);
}

public int getItemCount()
{
   return MyDataset.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public TextView postText;
    public ImageView postImage;

    public ViewHolder(View v)
    {
        super(v);
        postText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.myPostText);
        postImage = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.myPostImage);
    }

}
}
```

My model Data

```
public class MyDataModel {
String postText;
int postImgUrl;
 }
```

I am testing on real device through android studio, other apps i that i am also testing are fine.
Please help thank you.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: any errors or stack traces?

Comment: <pre>' 06-18 22:43:26.013 5702-   5702/com.example.grafiq.testviewapp   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.grafiq.testviewapp, PID: 5702
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.grafiq.testviewapp.MyAdapter.getItemCount(MyAdapter.java:43) ' </pre>

Comment: Is there anywhere you are initializing your data list MyDataset? if not, please do it in your constructor like MyDataset = new ArrayList<>() or something..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't initialize `MyDataset` inside `MyAdapter` class

Comment: Hi Chris, i did.. 
    **List<MyDataModel> MyDataset**

Comment: The answer is to initialize MyDataSet, the author declared the variable but didn't initialized it

Comment: Great answer Chris..I forgot to initialise the list under my constructor..it worked..I appreciate it man, gud job :)